# Implementing the Google Drive API with Google Sign In - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I am attempting to implement the Google Drive API into a project that is already using the Google Sign In SDK. I've added the scope for Google Drive to the GIDSignIn singleton, but the Drive API seems to require the user to sign in again. Is there a way to complete the authorization for the Google Drive API at the initial sign in through Google Sign In, rather than forcing the user to sign in twice?

I have read a similar question here, [Can I use google drive sdk with authentication info from google sign-in sdk on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187332/can-i-use-google-drive-sdk-with-authentication-info-from-google-sign-in-sdk-on-i), but the response never successfully creates a GTMOAuth2Authentication required by Google Drive from the GIDAuthentication returned by Google Sign In.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36383136/4024736

Comment: pretty unimpressive that Google are deprecating the old sign-in flow before even updating their documentation to use the new flow.

I suggest you send feedback on the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with my iOS app, and also checked out the similar question [Can I use Google Drive SDK with sign in information from Google Sign In SDK in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187332/can-i-use-google-drive-sdk-with-authentication-info-from-google-sign-in-sdk-on-i).  Drawing on the answer from Eran Marom, I was able to turn my Google Sign In credential into an OAuth2 credential, which I used to successfully access the Apps Script Execute API.

I worked in Swift.

In the App Delegate:

```
import GTMOAuth2

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

//Create an authorization fetcher, which will be used to pass credentials on to the API request
var myAuth: GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol? = nil

// [START didfinishlaunching]
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    let scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append(scopes)

    return true
}
//....

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {

        //sets credentials in fetcher
myAuth = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

        //...
    } else {
}
//....
```

In the ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleAPIClient
import GTMOAuth2

@objc(ViewController)

class ViewController: UITableViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

private let kClientID = "CLIENT ID"
private let kScriptId = "SCRIPT ID"
private let service = GTLService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
//...
}

func toggleAuthUI() {
    if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()){

        self.service.authorizer = appDelegate.myAuth
      //...  
    callAppsScript()
    } else {
//...
    }

@objc func receiveToggleAuthUINotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if (notification.name == "ToggleAuthUINotification") {
        self.toggleAuthUI()
        if notification.userInfo != nil {
            let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> =
                notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,String!>
            self.statusText.text = userInfo["statusText"]
        }
    }
}

func callAppsScript() {

    let baseUrl = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/\(kScriptId):run"
    let url = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(baseUrl, queryParameters: nil)

    // Create an execution request object.
    var request = GTLObject()
    request.setJSONValue("APPS_SCRIPT_FUCTION", forKey: "function")

    // Make the API request.
    service.fetchObjectByInsertingObject(request,
        forURL: url,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:")
}

func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject object : GTLObject,
                                                error : NSError?) {
//Display results...
}
```