# Error uploading file to Google Drive iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am getting following error "Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1001(null)" while uploading file to Google Drive. It was working fine but due to Google change in Authentication Policy and change in SignIn methods, I started getting "disallowed usergent" error and then I updated my code according to Google new policy. I also read that if you signIn using their new GoogleSignIn button, you are authenticated. However, with GoogleSignIn I am still using "GTMAppAuth" but still getting GMTOAuth2 error. I am writing correct authorization code for this error below.

In your AppDelegate, you need to declare "GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol" like this

```
@protocol GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate >

@property(nonatomic, strong, nullable) id<GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol> fetcherProtocol;

@end
```

In your GIDSignIn delegate function, you need to authorize this protocol like this.

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {

    if (error == nil) {
        // If you are Logged into google services!
        // Set GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol 

        _fetcherProtocol = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer;

    } else {
        // Error signing into Google services
    }
}
```

In UIApplication didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you need to define scope for your authorization flow.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes arrayByAddingObject:@[kGTLRAuthScopeDriveFile,kGTLRAuthScopeDrive]];
}
```

After that in main view controller, where you are using Google Drive Services, you need to authorize Google Drive with Authorization protocol

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

  //GTLR Google Drive property
_googleDriveService.authorizer = appDelegate.fetcherProtocol;

if([_googleDriveService.authorizer canAuthorize])
{
             // Here you will write code for Google Drive Service. 
}
```

Note, you can use this code to authorize any kind of Google Service. Thanks

Comment: You may want to check this [GitHub post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gtm-oauth2/2JfxZ48JdGE) for more information on the implementation of GTMAppAuth. As mentioned in the post, `GTMAppAuth` implements the `GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol` protocol, so the way you authorize your API requests using `GTMSessionFetcher` remains the same, but you need to switch to `GTMAppAuth` and update your authorization code to obtain authorization from the user in the new way for Google API services.

Comment: Yes, I am checking the following link. It's same what you are saying. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187332/can-i-use-google-drive-sdk-with-authentication-info-from-google-sign-in-sdk-on-i

Comment: I solved that authorization problem and you can see answer from above edited code.